# Creating A Customizable Count-Up Function in CSS, HTML or in Javascript?

Tags: html, css, math, counter

I have a countdown function (the code for which, is below) that is small and alligned to the top left corner.

I would like to be able to customize the size, allignment, back color, fore color, and also have a button to stop, start, and clear the timer. 
Secondly, I want the counter to show "00:00:00" at the start, and when it reaches "00:00:59", I want it to roll over to "00:01:00" showing that 1 minute has passed.

I would think that CSS/HTML would be the most appropriate language to do this in to acheive the desired visual effect but Javascript seems to have more arithmatic/parsing functionality.

```
<br><script language="JavaScript">
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
    s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
    if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2) {
        s = "0" + s;
        return "<b>" + s + "</b>";
    }
}

function CountBack(secs) {
    if (secs < 0) {
        document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
        return;
    }
    DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g,calcage(secs,86400,100000));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
    DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

    document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = DisplayStr;
    if (CountActive) {
        setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
    }
}

function putspan(backcolor, forecolor) {
    document.write("<span id='cntdwn' style='background-color:" + backcolor + "; color:" + forecolor + "'></span>");
}

if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined") {
    BackColor = "black";
}
if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined") {
    ForeColor= "white";
}
if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined") {
    TargetDate = "12/31/2050 5:00 AM";
}
if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined") {
    DisplayFormat = "%%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%%";
}
if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined") {
    CountActive = true;
}
if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined") {
    FinishMessage = "";
}
if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number") {
    CountStepper = -1;
}
if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined") {
    LeadingZero = true;
}


CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
if (CountStepper == 0) {
    CountActive = false;
}
var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
putspan(BackColor, ForeColor);
var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
var dnow = new Date();
if(CountStepper>0) {
    ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
}
else {
    ddiff = new Date(dthen-dnow);
}
gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
CountBack(gsecs);
</script>
```

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simpler solution, using javascript Date object, sum miliseconds on a time counter then format the miliseconds as time.

some references :
Date object and functions : http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Not what im looking for. picture a wrist watch with a stop/start timer, that is what i want. I honestly didnt think it would be this hard to make a proper timer in html/java.